# django email list field

Tags: python, mysql, django

I want to create field that hods list of emails. My model is like this :

```
class Alerts(models.Model):
    emails = MultiEmailField()
    events = models.OneToOneField(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

All good, but when this models is saved in DB it is like this

```
{
"id": 11,
"emails": "['ht@ht.com,  bb@bb.com']",
"events": 13
}
```

The list in 'emails' key is represented as a string "['ht@ht.com,  bb@bb.com']" , not as a list ['ht@ht.com,  bb@bb.com']. I tried different method, parsers and approaches, but without success. Is there a way to save list in DB or not? If it is the second is there a way to receive back a list as a response, not a string, that is fine too. ( DB is MYSQL)

Comment: There is no data type in MySQL to store ***an array of items***. The `MultiEmailField` is a wrapper which helps you to save/store some data in list/array form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`ListCharField`](https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_fields/list_fields.html#django_mysql.models.ListCharField) from `django-mysql` lib.

```
from django.db import models
from django_mysql.models import ListCharField

class Alerts(models.Model):
    emails = ListCharField(
        base_field=models.EmailField(...),
        ...
    )
    events = models.OneToOneField(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: болшой спасибо Timofey Katalnikov, that works perfect for me

Answer (score 1):

Django 3.1 added [`models.JsonField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField) which can be used for all DB backends. You can use this to store a list

```
class Alerts(models.Model):
    emails = models.JsonField()
```

Comment: yeeah, that's fine, but we don't use this version in our project, it's not option for me

Comment: You can use JsonField as an external package https://pypi.org/project/django-jsonfield/

Comment: I think that [`ListCharField`](https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_fields/list_fields.html#django_mysql.models.ListCharField) from `django-mysql` will be more suitable way in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can just split the string to get the emails in a list like this:

```
email_list = emails.replace("['", "").replace("']", "").split(",  ")
```

Comment: it run into my mind, but it's not clean and convenient way

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer of Dacx. And from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1894296/5731101

How about:

```
import ast

class Alerts(models.Model):
    raw_emails = MultiEmailField()
    events = models.OneToOneField(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def emails(self):
        return ast.literal_eval(self.raw_emails)
```